# Formatting parameterized custom label inside subject for Visualforce Email template

Tags: customlabel, parameters, formatting, visualforce-template

I'm trying to use the format() visualforce function to have a parameterized custom label as my Visualforce Email Template subject.

This is my current code:

```
    <messaging:emailTemplate
        subject="{!format($Label.GDPR_Contributor_Email_Notification_Subject, relatedTo.Owner.Name)}"
        recipientType="Contact" relatedToType="Opportunity">
    <messaging:htmlEmailBody >
        <html>
            <head></head>
            <body>
                ...
```

So, when trying to use format and saving I see the following error:

> Error: Unknown function FORMAT. Check spelling

Any idea why I can not use the format function inside a Visualforce Email Templates and workarrounds?

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Not saying this is a solution, but you have one left parentheses and two right parentheses.

Comment: @caleb.breckon yes, that wasn't in my actual code, I've updated the question

Comment: There is no format function in visualforce - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_functions.htm wgat are you trying todo?

Comment: @Rahul yes, I've just realized it is only for lightning components https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring16/release-notes/rn_lightning_labels_dynamic_params.htm

Comment: @Rahul I'm trying to use the custom label with parameters in a visualforce

Comment: see [apex:outputText](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_outputText.htm) with `apex:param`

Comment: @cropredy Hi, thanks for the suggestion, but I think I can not use that inside the email subject.

Comment: ah true - not avail for subject